# How to manually manage packet received by device in Kernel

Tags: c, networking, kernel

I would like to know how I could manually manage each packets received by a specific net device in the Kernel ? I do not want to use a socket, neither let the Kernel unpack them for me, or manage them for me. For example, if an ICMP packet comes, I would send an answer with my own module.

Comment: So, basically, you want to rewrite the entire network stack in your module? That's a rather large project....

Comment: The purpose is not tout rewrite the entire network stack, but just to try some things to understand how it's done ;)